# How do you uninstall roundcube?

Tags: debian, uninstall, roundcube

How do you uninstall roundcube in debian? It came with directadmin.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to find the extact package name from the list of installed packages using the command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i roundcube
```

Then, you can remove it using the commnand:

```
apt-get remove <package name>
```

Where `<package name>` is the name you got from the first command.

Comment: I don't get anything back from the first command. Will this remove roundcube database also?

Comment: Double-check the spelling of the word "roundcube". Try to use only part of the word like "round". If you did not get anything after those trials, you may not be able to uninstall it as a single package.

Comment: Still nothing, I think maybe it is because of Directadmin.

Comment: Usually, when you install a package that uses (depends on) several other packages. They are all installed as separate packages. Does directadmin comes as a single package that includes roundcube?